# How do I start with programming the AR.Drone quadrotor in ROS using openCV?

Tags: ros, opencv, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I would like to program an AR.Drone 2.0 using ROS in C++. However im still stuck on how to go about it from creating a package to what libraries to use and commands to get the video feed from the drone to openCV and to pass commands to the drone from the code. I went through the ROS tutorials with installation and creating packages and also have the ardrone_autonomy driver installed but am a bit overwhelmed with what I need from all the information. Im new to this area of work and would sincerely appreciate if someone can help me step by step on how I should begin.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74038/how-do-i-start-with-programming-the-ar.drone-quadrotor-in-ros-using-opencv?/) by [j_0101](https://answers.ros.org/users/6058/j_0101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You can use my [repository](https://bitbucket.org/alexbuyval/ardroneum/overview).
Please note it is not tutorial and we have not any documentations.
We are developing it for Russian competition of flying robots, so it contain many special code.
You can find examples of sending command to AR.Drone in navigation.cpp
Also you can find examples of using OpenCV in tag_detection.cpp.

Also you can find some examples in [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tum_ardrone) package

Regards, Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [learningpro](https://answers.ros.org/users/10636/learningpro/) on 2014-01-10**:
Hello  I can not get into your repository, I just want to see the examples how to control and use OpenCV, would you please let me know? learningpro.dong@gmail.com, thank you

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2014-01-15**:
Hi, I have shared repository for you.
Alex